# Check for similarity on different size images

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a video source that produce many streams for different devices (such as: HD television, Pads, smart phones, etc.), every of them has to be checked within each other for similarity. The video stream release 50 images per second, one image every 20 milliseconds.

Lets take for instance img1 coming from stream1 at time ts1=1, img2 coming from stream2 at ts2=1 and img1.1 taken from stream1 at ts=2 (20 milliseconds later than ts=1), the comparison result should look something like this:

compare(img1, img1) =   1          same image same size

compare(img1, img2) =   0.9       same image different size

compare(img1, img1.1) =     0.8       different images same size

ideally this should be done real time, so within 20 millisecond, the goal is to understand if the streams are out of synchronization, I already implemented some compare methods (nobody of them works for this case yet):

1) histogram (SSE and OpenCV cuda), result compare(img1, img2) ~= compare(img1, img1.1)

2) pnsr (SSE and OCV cuda), result compare(img1, img2) < compare(img1, img1.1)

3) ssim (SSE and OCV cuda), resulting the same as pnsr

Maybe I get bad results because of the resize interpolation method?

Is it possible to realize a comparison method that fulfill my requirements, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that you're running into a Real Problem (TM). This is not a trivial lets-give-it-to-the-intern problem.

The main challenge is that you can't do a brute-force comparison. HD images are 3 MB or more, and you're talking about O(N*M) comparisons (in time and across streams).

What you essentially need is a fingerprint that's robust against resizing but time-variant. And as you didn't realize that (the histogram idea for instance is quite time-stable, for instance) you didn't include the necessary information in this question.

So this isn't a C++ question, really. You need to understand your inputs.